# Percentage distribution of cells in all clusters based on their treatment condition?

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, ggplot2

I have 2151 cells, I clustered them by Seurat to 5 clusters. With the code below, I am able to have the number of cells per cluster and per condition:

```
number_perCluster<- table(object@meta.data$conditions, 
                          object@meta.data$clusterID)
```

Could I please get a hint on how I could proceed to produce a figure where I say: X% of cells treated with condition "Y" are located in cluster "C" and so forth?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `prop.table`, also if you want a figure, please describe it a bit more. This is usually better displayed as a table or heatmap, but perhaps you want something else...

Comment: Please don't also create a github issue on the Seurat page each time you ask a question here, there is no need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

```
library(Seurat) 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

meta.data <- pbmc_small[[]]

# create random classifications for the sake of this example
meta.data$condition <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), nrow(meta.data), replace = TRUE)

counts <- group_by(meta.data, condition, res.1) %>% summarise(count = n())

ggplot(counts, aes(res.1, count, fill = condition)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]